# Is there a way to make Launcher read icon from usb?

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons, usb-drive

Gnome in 10.04, and Nautilus still today under 12.04, read the autorun.inf file from my USB drive and display correctly the (`.ico`) icon for the given drive.

However, Unity's Launcher shows a generic icon. How can I change that? Is it possible to have it read the `.ico` (or, say, a `.png`) from within the drive? Or otherwise assign a specific icon to a particular device? -- i.e., I'm not interested in substituting one generic icon for another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity, it is not (yet) possible to do this, because Unity is coded to use the default system icon for removable drives, so you would need to [file a bug against Unity](https://askubuntu.com/q/2345/58950) asking for this functionality.